# EFCore not possible to find any compatible framework version

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, rider

I created a new simple net5.0 + EFCore project, but after trying to run `dotnet ef update --project DAL` I am getting an obscure error:

```
>dotnet ef update --project DAL
...
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
...
```

Even though, I am not using the `.NETCore 2.0.0` in the specified project, but rather the `net5.0` as shown in the `DAL.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I also tried to run the update with `--framework net5.0`, but with no difference.
What setting am I missing to convince `dotnet ef` to use correct framework.
(BTW. I am using the Rider, not VS), but I do not thing this matters.

Comment: Do you have a `global.json` file in your project structure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create EF migrations after installing .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998114/cant-create-ef-migrations-after-installing-net-6)

Comment: I voted to close this, because there is a duplicate, albeit with different answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998114/cant-create-ef-migrations-after-installing-net-6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was in the exactly same situation as you and solved my problem by adding the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package to the project.

Comment: This worked for me too. I thought that I didn't need `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` to be directly referenced in the project because it was transitively included via another project, but I got the error until I added it directly in the project I was trying to run `dotnet ef` against.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had this problem when trying to create a Migration, my CLI tool was old, updating it solved the problem:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

After that my command works:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialSchema
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the start-up project, and it must have the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package
it worked for me