# Can't create EF migrations after installing .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've just installed .NET 6 SDK and updated all my projects to use target `net6.0`, but when I try to create a new migration with the `dotnet` tool I get:

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ApplicationIcon>assets-logo.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <RootNamespace>LC.Assets</RootNamespace>
    <Authors>Stein Lundbeck</Authors>
    <Company>Lundbeck Consulting</Company>
    <Product>LC Assets</Product>
    <Copyright>2021</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="assets-logo.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LC.Components.Core\LC.Components.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LC.Components\LC.Components.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' (x64) was not found.
>
> The following frameworks were found:
> 6.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

I've updated the `dotnet-ef` tool to version 6.0.0, so I don't know what it is that still target the 2.0.0 version.

> Tool 'dotnet-ef' was successfully updated from version '5.0.4' to version '6.0.0'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you update the EF tool and still the migration failed? Can you publish your csproj file?

Comment: @Chaodeng I just added it to the question :)

Comment: You are lacking the opening <Project> tag. Is it just a bad copy/paste?

Comment: @Chaodeng jepp a formatting issue, fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem recently after upgrading to .NET6.

The solution for me was to follow the link in the error message and install Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.0/runtime

I'm guessing that the upgrade to 6 removed this framework as it is considered legacy ... BUT ... is still used (or marked as a required dependency somehow) in the dot net tools.

Comment: ok sounds good. I was about to install the runtime, but didn't know if it runs with 6.0 installed. thanks!

Comment: it worked! great!

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be required. Can you [submit an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new?assignees=&labels=customer-reported&template=bug_report_efcore.md) with your project attached (if possible) so we can investigate further?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the exact same issue.

Rather than installing Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.0., I installed the Entity Framework Core Design package:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

It made the error go away for me.

Note: I came upon the solution after remembering that following the EF Getting Started guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) had me install the Design package and didn't throw the error when I followed the guide.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was installing EntityFrameworkCore.Design as suggested by *@Thomas Z*.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

As well, making sure the path of the db is correct when creating the ef migration. It won't work if the path is dynamically created.